# Avoiding abstract classes and inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, domain-driven-design

consider I am having an *Event* with *Invitations* (each "invited person" represents an *Invitation*, so multiple *Invitations* are out for a single *Event*):

[image: Diagram]

```
[«aggregate root»;Invitation]<>1..*-[«value object»;EventIdentifier]
[«value object»;EventIdentifier]-<>[«aggregate root»;Event]
[«value object»;Invitee|emailAddress;facebookIdentifier]-<>[«aggregate root»;Invitation]
```

The *Invitee*, however, can bei **either** an Email Address **or** a facebookIdentifier, that's the nature of the business logic.
Usually I would have made an AbstractInvitee with FacebookInvitee and EmailInvitee, and created an association to the abstract, but that's evil as I know now.

Should I, instead, have actually *FacebookInvitee* and *EmailInvitee* and the *Invitation* has each a `facebookInvitee` and an `emailInvitee` property; and a Service or so would merge them together, if necessary?

Thanks for your advice!

**Edit**

I just came to the following idea which looks rather neat,

[image: Diagram]

```
[«value object»;Invitee|type;identifier]-<>[«aggregate root»;Invitation]
```

The `type` is somehow a constant with `FACEBOOK` and `EMAIL`, and the `identifier` then is the FB UID or the email address respectively.

Comment: Does the source of the invitee(a facebookinvitifier or an email address) affect the business logic desicion? Such as something could be only applied to facebookinvitee?

Comment: good question; well, as soon as it comes to notifications (like, "getting in contact" with the invitee), it somehow affects the BL. Despite that, I'd say everything else is just presentation related.

Comment: @AdrianFöder How exactly is an abstract value object evil ?

Comment: In many languages this data type would be called a [discriminated or tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). There is only one domain entity being represented, but there are two distinct ways to represent that entity. An abstract class with 2 concretions would be the idiomatic way to handle this case in traditional OOP languages like C# or Java. In functional languages you would likely represent this case with a variant, pattern matching between the two  cases. This is closer to your second example with its type identifier.

Comment: The explanation of variants in [Nemerle Language](https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/wiki/Grok-Variants-and-matching) gives a good example of the concept from a C# perspective, which might be a more accessible explanation than the wiki page.

Comment: @guillaume31 I'd say not exactly inheritance at all, but especially associations to abstract classes are really bad...

Comment: Why ? Bad in what respect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Usually I would have made an AbstractInvitee with FacebookInvitee and
>   EmailInvitee, and created an association to the abstract, but that's
>   evil as I know now.

**Inheritance is not that evil.**

If your classes `FacebookInvitee` and `EmailInvitee` have the same interface I see no reason to avoid inheritance. Inheritance adds complexity if interfaces are different and casting to concrete types is needed.

> The `type` is somehow a constant with `FACEBOOK` and `EMAIL`, and the
>   `identifier` then is the FB UID or the email address respectively.

Your example is very similar to [Replace Subclass with Fields](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceSubclassWithFields.html) refactoring. Anyway it will be needed to write `if-else` code-block to check invitee `type` and use its `identifier` for sending an invitation somewhere. Who should be responsible for it? In your solution `Invitee` is simply a DTO without behaviour. If `Invitee` has behaviour and can `Send()` an invitation itself then I would use inheritance and implement `Send()` for every concrete class (e.g. FacebookInvitee, EmailInvitee).

Answer (score 3):

I'd still keep an abstract `Invitee` value object with 2 derivatives `EmailInvitee` and `FacebookInvitee`.

Each type of Invitee can raise its own flavor of `WasNotified` [Domain Event](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) which is then captured by an Infrastructure layer notification service that knows how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I like your idea in edit.

You could place a NotificationService in the domain layer and add adapters in the infrastructure layer(FacebookNotificationService / EmailNotificationService).

And a NotificationDispatcher(it is also an adapter but aggregates other adapters) to dispatch notification(by invitee type) to the corresponding adapter.